# Finding probability based on mean and standard deviation.

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation, means

Suppose the scores of an entrance test are normally distributed.
Also, suppose the test has a mean of m and a standard deviation of s.
You have set the cut off as 90 marks for the test. What is the probability of a student passing the test?

E.g. For a mean of 100 and standard deviation of 10, this probability is 0.84.

However, What is the formula or method to arrive at this number?

Comment: Could you edit into your question what you have tried?

Comment: I would do it this way: Let $X \sim N(100,10)$. Then
$$
P(X>90) = 1- P(X<90) = 1- \Phi \left( \frac{90-100}{10} \right)
$$

Comment: @Henry I tried many things but I have not arrived on that answer.

Comment: Did you try my approach?

Comment: @MattiP. that worked, thanks! Can you add this as an answer and I will accept and upvote it.

Comment: In R, where `pnorm` is a normal CDF, code 1 - pnorm(90, 100, 10)` returns $0.8413447.$ Also (without additional parameters, `pnorm` is CDF of standard normal. As in @MattiP.'s comment, R code `1 - pnorm(-1)` gives same result. I suppose you would get $0.8413$ from a printed normal table.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very easy, standard question related to the normal distribution. We have a normally distributed variable $X \sim N(100,10)$. Then
$$
P(X>90) = 1- P(X<90) = 1- \Phi \left( \frac{90-100}{10} \right) \approx 0.841~344
$$
It was necessary to normalize the value inside the cumulative density function $\Phi$ because it is calculated for the $N(0,1)$-case.